# Discord api /users/@me/guilds rate limit

Tags: php, api, discord

I'm creating a Discord login feature where a user has to be in a specific guild to being able to log in a dashboard. Now I have been hitting the rate limit since 26-10-2022 20:30 and the rate limit is still here at this time.

These are the headers being returned from the guilds request:

```
array:22 [▼
  "retry-after" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "772"
  ]
  "x-ratelimit-reset" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "1664228738"
  ]
  "x-ratelimit-reset-after" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "1"
  ]
]
```

x-ratelimit-reset is an epoch time so i convert it

```php
$epoch = 1664228738;
$dt = new DateTime("@$epoch");  // convert UNIX timestamp to PHP DateTime
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // output = 2022-09-26 21:45:38
```

```
X-RateLimit-Reset - Epoch time (seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on January 1, 1970) at which the rate limit resets

X-RateLimit-Reset-After - Total time (in seconds) of when the current rate limit bucket will reset. Can have decimals to match previous millisecond ratelimit precision
```

Is there any way to request access or increase the amount of requests on this endpoint?

Comment: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits doesn't mention anything about that; apart from _"If you are experiencing repeated CloudFlare bans from the Discord API within normal operations of your bot, you can reach out to support to see if you qualify for increased global rate limits."_ - but that a) does not appear to be your issue (hitting CloudFlare bans), and b) I rather doubt they would give you more resources, for your intended purpose here.

Comment: @CBroe yes I have rate limited the amount of login attempts now, but for development purpose I have not  which probably have hitted the limit. I messaged the support and will wait for them if they can remove the probably cloudflare ban / rate limit. It’s just weird that after the limit resets it instantly hits the rate limit again.

Comment: You could check the console to see if there are multiple requests made after a user is logged in and / or redirected to your application. Are you working on localhost or a different environment?

Comment: @node_modules no there are 2 requests made per user ( Auth and guilds right afterwards ). Currently working on localhost due development which probably hitted the rate limit because of testing use cases.

Comment: I have same problem. Did you solve this?